# How to Set Different Privileges for Different Users of an Excel File

Tags: vba, authentication, userform

maybe you can help me with this issue:

I am trying to set for one excel sheet different kind of privileges.
For example, there will be an Admin with all right and a guest, how is only allowed the change an range of cells.
I started to setup 2 different kind of logins, the one for the admin is working well however the one for the guest not at all.
What am I doing wrong here?

Ps: I just started to learn VBA ☺

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim objTargetWorksheet As Worksheet
'Gast
  If (TextBox1.Value = "Gast" And TextBox2.Value = "123") _
Or (TextBox1.Value = "Amy" And TextBox2.Value = "345") _
Or (TextBox1.Value = "Paul" And TextBox2.Value = "456") Then
Me.Hide: Application.Visible = True

For Each objTargetWorksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  If objTargetWorksheet.Name = TextBox1.Value Then
    Range("K3:K50").Locked = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="12345", Contents:=True
  Else
   Range("K3:K50").Locked = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="12345", Contents:=True

  End If
Next
'Admin
ElseIf TextBox1.Value = "Admin" Then
    If TextBox2.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please Input the Password"
    ElseIf TextBox2.Value = "123" Then
        Me.Hide: Application.Visible = True
    Else
        MsgBox "Please Input the right User Name and the right Password"
    End If


  Else
    MsgBox "Please input the right user name and the right password"
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
  ThisWorkbook.Application.Quit
End Sub



Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
  ThisWorkbook.Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the sheet you are working on.

```
For Each objTargetWorksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  If objTargetWorksheet.Name = TextBox1.Value Then
    objTargetWorksheet.Range("K3:K50").Locked = True
    objTargetWorksheet.Protect Password:="12345", Contents:=True
  Else
    objTargetWorksheet.Range("K3:K50").Locked = True
    objTargetWorksheet.Protect Password:="12345", Contents:=True
  End If
Next
```

UPDATE: Cells are locked by default so you actually have to unlock them before protecting the sheet. Try this:

```
For Each objTargetWorksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  If objTargetWorksheet.Name = TextBox1.Value Then
    objTargetWorksheet.Cells.Locked = False
    objTargetWorksheet.Range("K3:K50").Locked = True
    objTargetWorksheet.Protect Password:="12345", Contents:=True
  Else
    objTargetWorksheet.Cells.Locked = False 
    objTargetWorksheet.Range("K3:K50").Locked = True
    objTargetWorksheet.Protect Password:="12345", Contents:=True
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer., however I still have the same problem that everything is protected, not just the Range (K3:K50).

Comment: I revised my code. Also the if is pointless as both pieces of code do the same thing.